# jquery .getScript and resource tracking

Tags: jquery

rather than use something like yepnope.js is there a simple method/decent plugin that can check if a resource has previously been loaded in, if not load it?

I have a number of ajax calls and should I load the same form in more than once the eventlisteners are duplicated for each load (so 4th time form is loaded 4 handlers doing same thing are called). This is because it is a web service making remote calls so I use $.getScript() to include the js I need...

I've seen [jquery resource loader](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/rloader) but wondered if there was any other options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using another lib for script loading, like [LABjs](http://labjs.com/) - it has option to prevent loading same script multiple times.

Comment: yes i think that does similar to yepnope but is a bit lighter (which is good). was hoping to find a jquery check so that I could extend the getScript method to add a parameter...

Comment: I don't know about any plugin for jQuery doing this, but you could make your own wrapper for `$.getScript`, logging every loaded script and assuring it is loaded only once. But it's reinventing the wheel in some way :/